# Changing image width before delivering for mobile website

Tags: php, css, image

I have desktop website in which I use images with size of 500*500. I use the same images for my mobile website.

Thing is it takes enormous amount of time for a mobile to download such large images. If I specify width & height attribute in `<img>`, it just displays it in a specified size, but it downloads the original image.

What's the best way to handle it? I can't manually change all the thousand of images' sizes & upload in a different folder.

Assigning `max-width` attribute in css does the job?

Comment: Why cant php change them all in a script and put them in a different folder? Check out the code example - https://github.com/Intervention/image

Comment: Yeah that can be possible, let me check this out. And thanks for a quick reply

Comment: If you are using bootstrap css, try giving class="img-responsive" to the images tag.

Comment: @PavithraAshwath Wont that just change the image display size but not the download size?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/ this may be useful also.

Comment: @PavithraAshwath That will change display size only, that's not the concern here.

Comment: @clonerworks yes, this will change the display size only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, you can calc image height - width using some JS and create URL accordingly and assign to img tag.

Assume on server under photos directory there is a photo with name 1.jpg

photo.php

```
<?php
require 'ImageResize.php';

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
if(file_exists('photos/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg')){

    $image = new ResizeImage();
    $image->load('photos/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');
    $image->resize($_GET['width'], $_GET['height']); //25-width, 30-height
    $image->output();
}
```

index.html

```
<img src="photo.php?id=1&width=25&height=30"/>
```

ImageResize.php

http://pastebin.com/mTRqfgMJ

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to store the new image size on the server also and check to see if that image size exists before you reprocess it again?

Comment: Answer is good enough, only question is, won't it impact the loading time?

Comment: No it shouldn't impact if your servers are good enough, also it will make your site responsive, if you will go with pre-defined size of images you will end up with doing adaptive site for few resolutions only.

Comment: Hey, images with 'blank space' in name are not loading with this, tried replacing blank with %20 but that didn't work. Any ideas why it's not able to load such images?

Comment: try below,

`<img src="photo.php?id=image%20with%20space.png&width=25&height=30"/>`

`if(file_exists('photos/'.urldecode($_GET['id'])))`

Answer (score 0):

No, max-width attribute doesn't change anything: your browser **have to download all the content of the image given in the src attribut before he can resize**. If you want a sizeless picture, you create it with another name and the size you want, then css can do a very good job for you.

```
<!--Replace...-->
<img src=imgurl>
<!--...by:-->
<span id=someid></span>
```

Then in your stylesheet add:

```
#someid{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url(imgurl) no-repeat;
}
/*next lines are gonna apply only if it's a mobile browser (css3)*/
@media handheld{
    #imgurl{
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        background: url(imgurl_resized_250) no-repeat;
    }
}
```

With this code, the span will show your picture with the size it needs.
**PS:** You can found on gogole some apps that can help you resize a folder of pictures, maybe [Format Factory](http://format-factory.en.softonic.com/) can help u?